# Is this Hadith authentic?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

Is the frequenctly quoted hadith authentic **"الکاسب حبیب اللہ"** ? If yes, then in which book ?

Comment: Is it a hadith at all? This is quoted in many books (mainly sufi books and some tafssirs of possibly sufi scholars -not sure-and further on persian websites, so it might also appear in Shi'a sources) as a saying addressed in passive voice without any refrence or attribution.

Answer (score 1):

This is not found in any [authentic] Hadith but some scholars have used it in their Tafseers such as:

- Tafsir-al-Baydawi [7/84]:

  وفيه مدح للسعي في طلب الرزق كما ورد: الكاسب حبيب الله، وهو لاينافي التوكل
- Tafsir-ruh-al-bayan [5/229] (Here the author quotes Rumi's Masnwavi):

  كر توكل ميكنى در كار كن ... كشت كن پس تكيه بر جبار كن
  رمز الكاسب حبيب الله شنو ... از توكل در سبب كاهل مشو
- Tafsir-Hadaiq-al-Rauh-Wa-al-Raihan-Fi-Rawabi-Ulum-al-Quran [21/262]:

  وهي {لِتَسْكُنُوا فِيهِ}؛ أي: في الليل، ثم بعلة الثاني، وهو النهار، وهي {وَلِتَبْتَغُوا مِنْ
  فَضْلِهِ}؛ أي: في النهار بأنواع المكاسب، وفي هذا مدح للسعي في طلب الرزق، كما ورد في
  الحديث: "الكاسب حبيب الله" وهو لاينافي التوكل"